# Next.js - getStaticProps returning undefined

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am trying to fetch data from an Api with graphQL but only successfully on the server side on the client side I am receiving undefined

Types

```
export type LogoProps = {
  alternativeText: string
  url: string
}


export type LandinPageProps = {
  logo: LogoProps
}
```

Index.tsx

```
const Index = ({ logo }: LandinPageProps) => (
  console.log(logo),      <<-------- undefined fetch
  (
    <>
 <SectionHero logo={logo} />
    </>
  )
)
```

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const landinPage = await client.request(GET_LANDING_PAGE)

  console.log(landinPage) <<-------- success fetch
  return {
    props: {
      ...landinPage
    }
  }
}

export default Index
```

GraphQL response

```
{
 landinPage: {
   logo: {
     alternativeText: 'React Avançado',
     url: '/uploads/logo_74e2fdc755.svg'
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please show content of `landinPage`? It's possible types are mismatched.

Comment: thanks for the reply follow the code below, https://github.com/GorillazJS/landingpage/blob/master/src/pages/index.tsx

Comment: Try const { landingPage} = await blablabla... landingPage is a property of the returned value, you are not destructuring the right variable.

Comment: @Morphyish thank you so much everything working normally =DD